# E/Toast: setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toasts, the values won't be used

Tags: android

I'm watching a lecture, but I got stuck in a place called "Showing the toast location."

If you enter the left (X coordinate) and right (Y coordinate) in the equation, the toast position is

They fly accordingly,

[image]

The purpose is to make it this way,

[image]

I entered the code as it was, and whatever value I entered

It only appears below.

Looking at the log

E/Toast: setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toast and no value is used.

I get this error, but I don't know what to do.

Help me, seniors...

MainActivity.java above is like this

The xml below is like that.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    EditText editText2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    }

    public void onButton1Clicked(View v) {
        try {
            Toast toastView = Toast.makeText(this, "위치가 바뀐 토스트 메시지입니다.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
            int xOffset = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()); 

            int yOffset = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

            toastView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, xOffset, yOffset);
            toastView.show();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:hint="X 위치"
            android:inputType="numberSigned" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:hint="Y 위치"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="띄우기"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="onButton1Clicked"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int) method doesn't work Android >= 11. Custom toasts aren't allowed for apps targetting Android API 30+.

Comment: Did you try `toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);`? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, it is same sadly, I think to right answer by ashu.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm facing same